# Truffle console error "Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert"

Tags: solidity, truffle, solidity-0.5.x

I compiled and migrated my solidity codes of erc20 token to development networks on truffle, and use it on truffle console.

```
truffle(development)> let instance = await XToken.deployed()
truffle(development)> let accountsArray = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
truffle(development)> instance.sendTxAndMessage(accountsArray[1], accountsArray[2], 60, "Hi!")
```

Then, I got error below:

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/Users/user/.nodebrew/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:1)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/Users/user/.nodebrew/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:1)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/Users/user/.nodebrew/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:1)
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/user/.nodebrew/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/~/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:96:1)
at /Users/user/.nodebrew/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:112:1
at /Users/user/.nodebrew/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth/~/web3-core-requestmanager/src/index.js:140:1
at Object.ErrorResponse (/Users/user/.nodebrew/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth/~/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:29:1)
```

So, does someone know how to handle this error?

Here is my solidiy code and truffle-config.js

XToken.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol;

contract XToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint8;
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    string public constant name = "XToken";
    string public constant symbol = "XTN";
    uint256 public constant decimals = 8;
    uint256 public _totalSupply = 5000000;

    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => string) public  receivedMessage;
    mapping(address => string) public  sentMessage;

    constructor (uint256 _initialSupply) public {
        balances[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
    }

    function airdrop(address _to, uint256 _value) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        transfer(_to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function sendTxAndMessage(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value, string memory _calldata) public returns (bool) {
        transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
        sentMessage[_from] = _calldata;
        receivedMessage[_to] = _calldata;
        return true;
    }

    function fetchReceivedMessage(address _to) public view returns (string memory) {
        return receivedMessage[_to];
    }

    function fetchSentMessage(address _from) public view returns (string memory) {
        return sentMessage[_from];  
    }
```

}

truffle-config.js

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
  },
}
```

And also, my environment is:
Truffle v5.0.5 (core: 5.0.5)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v10.9.0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are the reasons for the revert.```require(value <= _balances[from]);
        require(value <= _allowed[from][msg.sender]);
        require(to != address(0)); ```Can you confirm these conditions?

Comment: this could take a while to debug but if you want to message me, I will help you through every step of the way

Comment: @Lucas Rodriguez Benitez where to msg you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `transferFrom`, it is declared as external in [ERC20](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol).

When you execute `sendTxAndMessage`

```
     transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
```

It is equivalent to an external call

```
     ERC20(address(this)).transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
```

Then inside `trasnferFrom` you will have that `msg.sender` is the token address. So the call will fail if  `_from` have not authorized it.